How to Sum and Map Counts of Two Related Entities in TypeORM QueryBuilder?
I'm working on a TypeScript project using NestJS and TypeORM. I'm trying to build a query that retrieves a list of "tasks" with the following requirements:
Count the number of "incomplete subtasks" related to each task.
Count the number of "errored subtasks" related to each task.
Sum the counts of "incomplete subtasks" and "errored subtasks" for each task.
Here is my current findAllTasksQueryBuilder function:
private findAllTasksQueryBuilder(
  query: QueryParameters<TaskFilterableFields>,
  orderByRecords?: Map<string, string>
): SelectQueryBuilder<TaskEntity> {
  const queryBuilder = this.tasksRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("task")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("task.status", "status")
    .innerJoinAndMapOne(
      "task.assignedUser",
      UserEntity,
      "user",
      "user.id = task.createdBy"
    )
    .leftJoinAndSelect("task.subtasks", "subtask")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("subtask.subtaskStatus", "subtaskStatus")
    .addSelect(
      (subQuery) =>
        subQuery
          .select(
            "SUM(CASE WHEN subtaskStatus.code = :errorStatus THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)",
            "erroredSubtaskCount"
          )
          .from(SubtaskEntity, "subtask")
          .leftJoin("subtask.subtaskStatus", "subtaskStatus")
          .where("subtask.taskId = task.id"),
      "task.erroredSubtaskCount"
    )
    .addSelect(
      (subQuery) =>
        subQuery
          .select(
            "SUM(1)",
            "incompleteSubtaskCount"
          )
          .from(TaskEntity, "task")
          .leftJoin("task.incompleteSubtasks", "incompleteSubtask")
          .where("task.id = task.id"),
      "task.incompleteSubtaskCount"
    )
    .addSelect(
      "COALESCE(SUM(erroredSubtaskCount + incompleteSubtaskCount), 0)",
      "task.totalSubtaskCount"
    )
    .setParameter("errorStatus", SubtaskStatusEnum.ERROR)
    .groupBy("task.id, subtask.id, subtaskStatus.id")
    .take(query.top)
    .skip(query.skip);

  this.applyOrderBy(queryBuilder, orderByRecords);
  this.applyFilter(queryBuilder, query);
  this.applyCreatedDateFilter(queryBuilder, query);

  return queryBuilder;
}




 **.addSelect(
      "COALESCE(SUM(erroredSubtaskCount + incompleteSubtaskCount), 0)",
      "task.totalSubtaskCount"
    )**

Does not seems to be working. TypeORM is adding extra , and all in generated query.
What I've Tried:

Ensuring that the relations (incompleteSubtasks and subtaskStatus)
are properly defined in the respective entities. Attempted to group
by the necessary fields to avoid SQL errors.

Questions:

How can I correctly sum the counts of "incomplete subtasks" and
"errored subtasks" in a single query using TypeORM? Is there a
better way to structure this query to achieve the desired outcome?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

